# c# derive a class from a component

Tags: c#, .net, components, derived-class

I have derived a class from a component (DataGridView). How do I place my component in the visual studio components palette.

```
 class WorkerGrid:DataGridView
{
    public Worker Worker { get; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

    public void Load()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-automatically-populating-the-toolbox-with-custom-components

Comment: Insted of adding a class, I added a Component. Then derived from DataGridView and now I can see the component in the palette. Thanksfor the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-automatically-populating-the-toolbox-with-custom-components)

**Creating the Project**

The first step is to create the project and to set up the form.

- Create a Windows-based application project called ToolboxExample
  (**File** > **New** > **Project** > **Visual C#** > **Classic
  Desktop** >    **Windows Forms Application**).
- Add a new component to the project. Call it DemoComponent.

  - (For more information, see NIB:**How to: Add New Project Items**.)
- Build the project.
- From the **Tools** menu, click the **Options** item. Click General under the
  **Windows Forms Designer** item and ensure that the **AutoToolboxPopulate**
  option is set to **True**.

---

**To create an instance of a custom component**

- Open the project's form in the **Forms Designer**.
- In the **Toolbox**, click the new tab called **ToolboxExample Components**.
- Once you click the tab, you will see **DemoComponent**
- Drag your component onto your form. An instance of the component is
  created and added to the **Component Tray**.

[image]